# ng-bind equivalent in Angular

Tags: angular

I've used ng-bind in angularjs like this

```
<div ng-bind="getVal()"></div>
```

where `getVal()` return some value and it was in the controller.
But In Angular2 , I have a function `getVal()` in the component and I need to call it from the template, in the same way like angular1.

I tried

```
<div [(ngModel)]="getVal()"></div>
```

But no luck, any idea?

Comment: That is not two-way binding. You can just use `{{ getVal() }}`

Comment: Ah yes, it's not two way binding,my mistake, but imagine if I have a <input > instead of <div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 html binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Of course `{{ getVal() }}` will work as JB Nizet suggests when you want the returned value of your function to appear somewhere inline in the body of some HTML string.  However, what you're actually after is...

**Angular 1 Style:**

```
<div ng-bind="getVal()"></div>
```

**becomes...**

Angular 2+ **ng-bind** equivalent:

```
<div [textContent]="getVal()"></div>
```

Angular 2+ **ng-bind-html** equivalent:

```
<div [innerHtml]="getVal()"></div>
```

Comment: It should be `<div [textContent]="getVal()"></div>` for **ng-bind** `<div [innerHtml]="getVal()"></div>` for **ng-bind-html**

Comment: Should @JamiePate's comment not be integrated with the answer? ng-bind is not the same as [innerHtml]...

Comment: @toxaq, I integrated the additions.