# How to remove whitespace at the beginning of my json angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I add a json which send me that

```
{"idCommande":73864,"status":"error"}
```

My issue is when I put my json in

```
<code>
    <pre>
        {{ jsonFormatter | json}}
    </pre>
</code>
```

it add automatically in my json whitespace before my first `{` and after my last `}` for no reason.

I already try to do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data).replace(/\s(?=\w+":)/g, ""))`

But it's still the same issue

[image: whitespace]

Answer (score 3):

`<pre>` preserves whitespace, including the initial indentation. You could make sure the initial expression is not indented, like so:

```html
<code>
    <pre>
{{ jsonData | json }}
    </pre>
</code>
```

Only problem is that it doesn't look great, and your IDE might "fix" the indentation at some point without you noticing. A better way is to just use `ng-bind`. Not only is it a [more performant best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/4028303), but it also happens to address your issue as well by not including leading whitespace.

```html
<code>
    <pre ng-bind="jsonData | json"></pre>
</code>
```

P.S. I renamed jsonFormatter to jsonData in my example because I really couldn't make any sense of passing a formatter into AngularJS's `json` filter, which is itself a formatter. Consider a better name for this property.

Comment: just what i needed...  if you are in angular 2+ and want to use the equivalent of `ng-bind`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582803/7085047